# Regex help ... to strip blanks only in certain combinations

Tags: php, regex

I am not a regex specialist unfortunately. So, I searched here and used some regex I found. That "half solves" my requirements already, now I search for the small missing piece.

In general, I am working on lines of code with PHP's built in `tokenizer`. At the end, I get a code string containing `Whitespace`, `Tabs`, and `breaks`. What I found here already cleaned this "unnecessary whitespace". But I would like to go a bit further:

`$foo [ 'bar' ], $foo ['bar' ], $foo [ 'bar']` (containing some blanks)

should all go to: `$foo['bar']` (no blanks anymore)

```
$foo [ "bar" ], $foo ["bar" ], $foo [ "bar"]
```

should go to: `$foo ["bar"]`

BUT: `$foo [ 'this is different' ]` shall go to `$foo['tis is different']` (retaining the significant blanks)

At the moment I use:

```
$_S = array( " [", " '", "' ", " ]" );
$_R = array( "[", "'", "'", "]" );
$_tx = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $A_tx);
$_tx = str_replace( $_S, $_R, $_tx );
```

But for sure, the work can also be done with only one, more sophisticated regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a single pattern, one option could be making use of 2 capture groups and an alternation with a branch [reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).

I assume that `$foo['tis is different']` should be `$foo['this is different']`

In the replacement use the 2 groups `$1$2`

```
\$\w+\K(?|\h*(\[)\h*('[^']+')\h*|(\h*\[)\h*("[^"]+")\h*)(?=])
```

The pattern matches

- `\$\w+` Match `$` and 1+ word chars
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `\h*(\[)\h*('[^']+')\h*` Capture `[` in **group 1** and the opening till closing `'` in **group 2**, and match all the surrounding spaces to be removed
  - `|` Or
  - `(\h*\[)\h*("[^"]+")\h*` Capture the spaces and `[` in **group 1** and the opening till closing `"` in **group 2** and match the spaces around the `"` only
- `)` Close branch reset group
- `(?=])` Assert a `]` char directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hPIu4e/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/naVET)

```
$re = '/\$\w+\K(?|\h*(\[)\h*(\'[^\']+\')\h*|(\h*\[)\h*("[^"]+")\h*)(?=])/m';
$str = '$foo [ "bar" ], $foo ["bar" ], $foo [ "bar"]
$foo [ \'bar\' ], $foo [\'bar\' ], $foo [ \'bar\']
$foo [ \'this is different\' ]';

$result = preg_replace($re, '$1$2', $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
$foo ["bar"], $foo ["bar"], $foo ["bar"]
$foo['bar'], $foo['bar'], $foo['bar']
$foo['this is different']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Maybe I was not too exact in my question, sorry for that. The desired solution should also vover multi-dim Arrays such as $foo[ 'abc'][     "def"][    "xyz"   ] which I found that the offered solution does not cover. It cuts away the first key-part. At least in my code ... maybe it's due to the first regex that cuts away line-breaks, tabs etc?

Comment: @jwka Perhaps like this? https://regex101.com/r/IPTrkA/1

Comment: Very sorry! I guess i made an error when taking your soulution into my code. now it works ... I just re-checked. I must have done something wrong at the first try out. The only thing I hoped for was to have ONE regex for everything.

Comment: @jwka Does this meet the requirements of multiple values? https://3v4l.org/cPTrl

Comment: yes, it works just fine. Thanks! Would it be possible to have the cleaning of tabs and cr-lf ( '/\s+/') also included in ONE preg_replace? As far as I understood your solution there could be one more regex" BEFORE your and for the rplacement, there would then be $1$2$3 ?